Replace object in video
New at this, currently playing with free stuff like Clipchamp and veed ai text to video.  Before I invest in more pro level software, I want to know if it can easily do the types of things I want to do.  Here's my question for one such use-case:
I have a video of a person sitting and reading a book.  They turn the page and as they do for a moment you see some of the content on the page.
I want to replace the book with a different "new" book.   I can easily get images of the front, back, and spine of the new book, as well as a page or two inside.  Is there a name for this object replacement, and/or for the technique to do it, or possible techniques if more than one technique for doing so?  What is a good (hopefully cost-effective) software that can do this relatively easily?
Similar use-case:  Someone is drinking a can of soda, and I want to replace which brand of soda they are drinking, following the movement of bringing the soda can to their lips and taking a sip.
Thanks in advance for any useful answers.

You are describing Compositing, the process of combining elements from different sources into a single video. You will need a motion graphics application to create your projects. Examples are Adobe After Effects or Apple Motion.
Compositing is created by using layers of video or still images which move independently of each other. I will describe the soda can project as it is simpler than the book project. However, both utilize the same types of elements and procedures.
In the motion graphics application you will start with a base layer consisting of your original footage. In order to isolate and replace the soda can with a different one, you have to make a traveling mask layer and a layer for the new soda can.
You can make masks directly in the compositor, or you can make them in an image editor such as Adobe Photoshop.  In either you can use selection tools to select the can, and then convert the raster selection to a vector mask. Or you can draw the vector mask directly with the Beziér curve tool. If there are fingers or parts of the person's hand blocking part of the can, your mask will have to exclude those as well.
On a new layer position the mask over the can at the beginning of the video clip. If the motion of the soda can is smooth, you can advance to the end of the video and reposition the mask layer to match the video layer. This gives you the mask's beginning and ending positions. You will probably have to make intermediate key frames on the mask layer, unless the motion is linear. At each key frame you adjust the position of the mask to follow the motion. You may have to change the properties of the motion curve to make it smooth. The motion curve is a Beziér curve with points and handles, like a vector drawing, which affect speed and direction.
If the motion of the soda can is more complex, you can use the compositor's object following function to generate the motion path. This is too complex to describe here, and differs by software platform.
Once you have your motion path and mask defined, make another layer for the new soda can. At the beginning of the video place the new image inside the mask. The new image will now follow the direction and speed of the motion mask layer, replacing the original soda can.
Once the motion and image match the original, you then render the video and encode it in a video format like .mov or .mp4. You will have many output options to match the format you require.
These concepts are the same for any compositing or motion graphics program, but the details will be different. I have experience with Adobe After Effects, so this description is based on that.

Excellent answer.   Perfect level of detail in terms of what I was looking for.  Thank you.
